# How to set a single timer for two mouse events?

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouseevent

I have a trayicon and popup. I have used TrayIcon for setting icon on desktop traybar and Jframe for popup. When some notifications come popup appears.The popup fades away after 20 secs.If user hovers either on trayicon or popup within these 20 secs the timer should stop.So, how can I get a single timer for two events.Any help would be very needful.